# What was Jesus' mission in saying that He was 'in the Father' according to John 14:10 in the Bible?

Tags: john, jesus, 1-corinthians, christology

2 Corinthians 5:19 King James Version

> To wit, that God was **in** Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation.

This verse is often understood to express the idea that God, through Christ, reconciled the world to Himself. The term "reconciliation" here refers to the restoration of a friendly relationship between God and humanity. The verse emphasizes that God, in His mercy, does not hold people's trespasses against them. Instead, through Christ, there is an opportunity for reconciliation between humans and God. Additionally, it mentions that believers are entrusted with the "word of reconciliation," suggesting a responsibility to share the message of God's reconciling love with others.

Jesus states that the words He speaks and the works He does are not of His own initiative but are the result of the Father dwelling in Him. This highlights the divine nature of Jesus and His complete alignment with the will of the Father.

John 14:10 King James Version

> Believest thou not that I am **in** the Father, and the Father in me? the words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but the Father that dwelleth in me, he doeth the works.

What was Jesus' mission in saying that He was 'in the Father' according to John 14:10 in the Bible?

Comment: I am not sure that John 14:10 is a mission statement of Jesus - that is found in John 3:15-17.  (similar to 2 Cor 5:19.)  In John 14:10 is more a statement of means - the way that Jesus accomplished His mission by obeying the Father and setting sinners an example to follow.

Comment: I understand a little bit. What was Jesus' role in the Father?

Comment: The issue is being clouded by the addition of words (and therefore concepts) which are _not expressed_ in scripture viz : _the restoration of a friendly relationship between God and humanity_ and _an opportunity for reconciliation_ and _Jesus' mission_. By adding such words, the meaning of the text is clouded. It would be better to simply state the text and focus on what it _actually_ means. . . . . . . .

Comment: Through the Logos, Jesus fulfills a significant role within the Father

Comment: Since you focus only one part of what Jesus says in 14:10, it appears you are intenionally misstating the verse. You highlight one side “I *am* (note the ellipsis) **in** the Father…” and dismiss what is simultaneously true “and the Father **in** me is.” You cannot speak of a one-sided mission.

Comment: The action of logos is trilateral and dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

essentially the same as John 10:30. Jesus is the new man, with a spirit united morally and spiritually with the Word who is God. So unlike us, inundated with sin and sinful inclination, Jesus’ spirit is constantly humanly initiated by the divine nature intrinsic to his being, though the two natures are distinct within him. Thus, the divine will is clear to his humanity and is his desire. He is therefore the perfect human son, making the way for sonship as he demonstrated it perfectly. He humanly always does what pleases the Father and through that unity displays Him.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).